# SQL complains about a non-existing constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm really stumped on this one. We had a table with a two part primary key. The parts were a review_id (a foreign key from another table) and a time-stamp. Whoever designed this table didn't realize that some situations could result in two entries having identical time-stamps, and I was getting "ORA-00001: unique constraint" errors.

However, as this table was a log, it had no real need to have a primary key in the first place, so I removed the primary key constraint. Despite this constraint no longer existing, I'm still getting the same error.

I've tried adding elements to the PK to prevent the conflict as well as restoring the constraint but disabling it. Oracle SQL Developer insists that the database reflects the changes I've made, but the behavior suggests that it's still using the original PK. I thought it might be a caching problem, but even a complete reboot of my computer doesn't change it.

Any advice is appreciated.

An example of the commands I've run:

```
alter table "DATABASE"."DB_REVIEW_LOG" drop constraint "DB_REVIEW_LOG_PK";
update database.db_review_log set review_id=17494 where review_id = 17495;
```

and this is what I get back:

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
update database.db_review_log set review_id=17494 where review_id = 17495
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DATABASE.DB_REVIEW_LOG_PK) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Comment: Is there still a unique index on the `review_id` and the timestamp?  My guess would be that you dropped the primary key but didn't drop the unique index.

Comment: PLease show all relevant DDL.

Comment: Justin, Oracle SQL Developer will list all constraints in use, so I can confirm that the constraint it's listing no longer exists.

Comment: Actually, you were right. I was getting my terminology mixed up a bit, I guess. There was indeed still an index causing the problems. Not sure why it was calling the index a constraing in the error message, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that despite it complaining about a constraint, the problem was a unique index with the same name that was causing the problems.
Thank you, Justin Cave